# Replace values of two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

What is the fastest way to replace values of two columns in pandas? Let's say given is:

```
A B
0 2
1 3
```

and we want to get:

```
A B
2 0
3 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code flips the values between the columns:

```
>>> df_name[['A', 'B']] = df_name[['B', 'A']]

>>> print(df_name)
A  B
2  0
3  1
```